# Concanate class 'str' array to dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, concatenation

I am scraping stock infos from onvista.de like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

hdr={'User-Agent':'Chrome/70.0.3538.110'}

table_dfs={}

for page_number in range(3):
    http= "https://www.onvista.de/aktien/finder/?continent[0]=Europa&continent[1]=Nordamerika&continent[2]=Asien%20-%20Pazifik&PROFIT_PER_SHARE[enabled]=1&PROFIT_KGV[enabled]=1&MARKET_CAPITALIZATION[enabled]=1&PERFORMANCE_6_MONTHS[enabled]=1&PERFORMANCE_4_WEEKS[enabled]=1&SCREENER_INTEREST[enabled]=1&SCREENER_RISK_ZONE[enabled]=1&PROFIT_PER_SHARE[year]=2020&PROFIT_KGV[year]=2020&MARKET_CAPITALIZATION[year]=2020&offset={}".format(page_number*50)

    url= requests.get(http,headers=hdr)
    table_dfs[page_number]= pd.read_html(url.text)
```

I try to conatenate the results to a single dataframe with colums, I tried this:

```
df = pd.concat(table_dfs)
```

But this results in the error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'list'>"; 
only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
```

The output of `table_dfs[0]` looks something like this:

```
[       WKN                          Wert                  Branche  \
 0   A2PSR2           BIONTECH SE SP.ADRS           Biotechnologie   
 1   A1JA81               PLUG POWER INC.       Elektrotechnologie   
 2   A0B733                           Nel  Sonstige Energie / R...   
 
               Land Gewinn pro Aktie (€)     KGV  \
 0      Deutschland          Deutschland     NaN   
 1              USA                  USA   -26.0   
 2         Norwegen             Norwegen     0.0   
 
     Marktkapitalisierung (Mio. €) Performance - 6M (%)  Performance - 4W (%)  \
 0                             NaN                  000            6139.00000   
 1                             NaN             12.76665           43430.00000   
 2                             NaN              3.97097            8434.00000   
 
     Chance-Rating (the Screener)  Risiko-Rating (the Screener)  Unnamed: 11  
 0                           1888                           NaN          NaN  
 1                           1962                           4.0          0.0  
 2                           -705                           1.0          0.0 ]
```

My goal is to get this data into a csv file (all rows conconated).

Thanks for any help

Comment: may you should use `*` to unpack it `concat(*table_dfs)` or maybe you should use `for`-loop to add every item separatelly - `for table in table_dfs: df = df.concat(table)`. You should check documentation for `concat()`

Answer (score 0):

`read_html()` searchs all `<table>` on page and convert every `<table>` to `DataFrame` and it gives list with all `Dataframe`s (even if it found single `<tabel>` on page, or evne if it doesn't found any table) and you have to use `[0]` to get first `DataFrame` from list.

```
pd.read_html(response.text)[0]
```

---

I see other problem: you keep items in `dictionary` and when you use `concat(table_dfs)` then it will get `keys` from dictionary, not `values` with `DataFrames`. You would have to use `table_dfs.values()` or you should use `list` instead of `dictionary`.

---

Other problem: all `DataFrames` have the same indexes and after concatenation you will have three times index `0`, three times index `1`, etc. like `[0..49, 0..49, 0..49]`, You could use  `concat(..., ignore_index=True)` to have indexes `[0...149]`

---

My working code.

I changed some names and format code (see: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) )

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/70.0.3538.110'}  # PEP8: spaces around `=`

payload = {
     'continent[0]': 'Europa',
     'continent[1]': 'Nordamerika',
     'continent[2]': 'Asien - Pazifik',
     'PROFIT_PER_SHARE[enabled]': 1, 
     'PROFIT_KGV[enabled]': 1,
     'MARKET_CAPITALIZATION[enabled]': 1,
     'PERFORMANCE_6_MONTHS[enabled]': 1,
     'PERFORMANCE_4_WEEKS[enabled]': 1,
     'SCREENER_INTEREST[enabled]': 1,
     'SCREENER_RISK_ZONE[enabled]': 1,
     'PROFIT_PER_SHARE[year]': 2020,
     'PROFIT_KGV[year]': 2020,
     'MARKET_CAPITALIZATION[year]': 2020,
     'offset': 0,
}

url = 'https://www.onvista.de/aktien/finder/'

table_dfs = []  # list

for offset in range(0, 3*50, 50):

    payload['offset'] = offset

    response = requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers)
 
    all_tables = pd.read_html(response.text)
    table_dfs.append( all_tables[0] )  # `[0]` - first DataFrame from list
    
    #print(type(all_tables), all_tables)
    #print(type(all_tables[0]), all_tables[0])
    
df = pd.concat(table_dfs, ignore_index=True)

print(len(df))
print(df)
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thx. I will read the style guide ;-)